# showreel length

Tags: showreel

what's the recommended length a sound design showreel should be? is 8 or 10min a good length or too long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two minutes would be ideal with your best material in the first 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

8 minutes is way too long.  I'd keep it down under 90 seconds if possible.

Comment: Agreed.  That's half a reel! ;)  Mine is just shy of 4 min and I too feel it's too long.  Hope to cram it under 3 when new content is available for display.